# How to Ignore case when assigning json object to class in angular 4?

Tags: json, angular, mapper

I have a  `sample.model.ts`

```
export class sample
{
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
}
```

In my `sample.component.ts` I have created object of this class

```
model = new sample();
```

Now when I get data from `http Get` request I directly passing into model

```
(response: Response) => {
  this.model = response.json();
​}
```

It working fine only if i get same property name as model ex- if `json` obj return `firstName` then it map with my sample.model's `firstName` but if json object return `FirstName` or `firstname` then it will not map with my model.

Is there any option to map `json` object with my model class with case ignore (like upper or lower case)?

Comment: Nope, I don't think that there is a way...